# Grouping by interval with NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, group-by, intervals

How can I modify the following query to do the grouping without LINQ?

```
public class Entity
{
    public long Time { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Entity> Query(long interval)
{
    using (var session = m_sessionManager.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.QueryOver<Entity>()
            .Where( /* complex query */ )
            .List()
            .GroupBy(e => e.Time / interval)
            .Select(e => e.First());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to do it?  HQL, direct SQL, ???

Comment: Can I do it with the QueryOver API?

Comment: Ignore me.  I didn't read the question title properly.

Answer (score 0):

it is really hard to understand what do you want from your query it would be better if you post the sql query that you want to write in `QueryOver<>` API.
but i hope this will help you :

```
return session.QueryOver<Entity>()
            .Where( /* your complex query */)
            .SelectList(list => list
                .SelectGroup(e => e.Time / interval)
                .SelectSum(e => e.whatever))
                .List</*what do you want to select a list of what*/>()
                .Select( e=> e.First ) //what is First and why it is with() is it a property??
                .ToList<...>();
```

There are alot of things you can do with [QueryOver<> API](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)